# Why is application behavior on Expo-Snack different on Android emulator?

Tags: react-native, expo

in expo-snack the application drawer menu can appear when we click and drag with the mouse, but when we run the application in android emulator does not work when clicking and dragging to appear the menu.

https://snack.expo.io/@rafaelsl/2c568f

Comment: Did you run standalone apk or expo client in Android emulator?

Comment: I did run standalone apk in Android emulator!

Comment: Did you test on device, not emulator?